# How to get the object from JFrame2 on closing in Jframe1?

Tags: java, jframe

I am new to Java Development, i have a Jframe1 which opens a new window Jframe2 with the object passing inside the constructor like this,

```
final EmployeeLookUp f = new EmployeeLookUp(this);
```

And the Jframe2 constructor looks like,

```
 public EmployeeLookUp(LibraryHR lhr1) {
        initComponents();
        lhr = lhr1;
    }
```

Am making some changes inside the object lhr and i want to pass the modified object back to the Main frame On clicking the ok button. How can i do that?

```
final EmployeeLookUp f = new EmployeeLookUp(this);
f.show();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        f.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                //i want to get the object from Jframe2 to here
            }
        } );
```

**EDIT:**

My question is how to pass the object in Frame2 to Frame1 in closing event of  Frame2?

Comment: both the reference `lhr1` and `lhr` will point to same object so any changes made by one reference will change the object. No need to pass the modified object.

Comment: @Braj I think i have not made the question clear, its not about the object, i want to get the object in the closing event on the main frame.

Comment: Share the relevant code to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth reading [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Both the reference `lhr1` and `lhr` will point to same object in the memory so any changes made by one reference will change the original object.

Understand it visually.

[image]